# SIGINT ignored by multiple processes

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, signal-handling

I would like to create three processes, which would print some stuff till I press ctrl+c. Below you can see my try but when a try to stop the program nothing happens. When the only one child is forked, it works good. Where could be a problem? Thanks in advance.

```
     void my_handler(int s){
          printf("Caught signal %d, I am dying\n",s);
       exit(1);
     }

     void doChild(int count){
     fprintf(stdout,"Child %d with pid: %d\n",count, getpid());
    }


     int main(int argc, char **argv){

     int count = 0;
     pid_t pid;
     struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
     sigIntHandler.sa_handler = my_handler;
     sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
     sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
     sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
     fprintf(stdout, "Ahoj svjete!\n");

     for(;count < 3;count++){
            pid = fork();
    switch(pid){
             case -1:
                    perror("Fork :(");
                     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

             case 0:
                     while(1){
                            doChild(count);
                    }
       }
    }

     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: the parameters to main(), 'argc' and 'argv' are not used.  the compiler will raise a warning for each of those unused parameters.   suggest 1) compile with all warnings enabled, fix those warnings.  For the above pair of warnings, suggest 'int main( void );

Comment: the checking of the returned value from 'fork()' is only checked for the last call to fork, not for the prior calls.  suggest moving the checking of the pid value to inside the 'for' loop.

Comment: using tabs for indentation, as you can see in the posted code, is a very bad idea.  suggest indent consistently for the sake of us human readers.  suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: Firstly, its just a part of the code...I am going to write some getopt and stuff  :) Secondly, you are right I did not realise that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for(;count < 3;count++){
    pid = fork();
}
```

you will create a total of **8 processes**, as you are executing `fork()` 3 times, i.e. 1. call to `fork()` gives you 1*2=2 processes, 2nd call to `fork()` gives you 2*2=4 processes and 3rd call to `fork()` gives you 4*2=8 processes.

Moreover, the way you setup your signal handler you will be sending your signal to the entire [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) (e.g. parent and children). If this is not what you want, you should look at [`setpgid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpgid) and [`setsid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) functions to make the signal work separately for every child process.

**EDIT:**

Here is a modified version of your code with some additions from me that will help you understand what is going on. You can also find some more explanation as to what is happeninng in your code in Chris Dodds's answer. Sending a signal will now kill all the children and parent process but this code is just an example for you to learn how it works (as I said, you should probably use process groups here).

```
void my_handler(int s){
    printf("Caught signal %d, I am dying, my PID=%d\n",s, (int)getpid());
    exit(1);
}

void doChild(int count){
    fprintf(stdout,"Child %d with pid: %d\n",count, getpid());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int count = 0;
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    for(;count < 2;count++){
        pid = fork();
    }

    printf("My PID=%d\n", (int)getpid());
    fprintf(stdout, "Ahoj svjete!\n");

    switch(pid){
        case -1:
            perror("Fork :(");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            signal(SIGINT, my_handler);
            while(1){
                doChild(count);
            }
        default:
            printf("Parent\n");
            sigignore(SIGINT);
            wait(&status);
    }

    printf("Process %d ended life.\n", (int)getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem with number of processes...But signal handling still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As REACHUS notes, you get 8 processes, not 3.  Moreover, the switch tests the result of the *last* fork calll in each process, so 4 of the processes immediately exit, while the other 4 remain running in the `doChild` loop.

Now because the top-level process (the initial process that did the first fork) is one of those that exits (its `fork` calls all return the pids of children, never 0), the shell takes over again, which means that when you hit <kbd>ctrl-C</kbd>, it goes to the shell and not to your forked children.  Those children never see a SIGINT (unless you send it to them explicitly with `kill`), so never exit.